# Current carrying wires

Tags: applications

A current carrying wire takes the form of a plane circular loop of radius a. If the current in the loop is I, find the magnetic firld strength B at a point on the axis of the circle, distance b from the centre.

I think I'm supposed to use the Biot-Savart Law, but I don't know how to integrate everything in the form I have it in.

Comment: why are you asking this question in math forum this is related to"magnetic effect of current".If you want help in calculation then give the equation to evaluate.

Comment: becuase I'm on a maths course and it's an integration which i can't calculate, not a question about the theory behind it

Comment: Write the expression to calculate

Comment: integrate (0,dy,dz)x(b,-y,-z) over a circle of radius a

Comment: can't you write it in mathematical expression cause i couldn't understand it

Comment: okay try this link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html

Comment: @Tom: Welcome to math.SE! As iostream has pointed out, this is a mathematics site. Please don't assume knowledge about physics. If you need help with an integration, please write out the full integral that you're trying to evaluate, and please do so in the question, as people shouldn't have to read through the comments to understand the question. There's an edit link underneath the question. For help on typesetting mathematics on this site, please see [this FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

The Biot-Savart law tells us that the magnetic field is given by
$$\mathbf{B} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_O\frac{I\mathrm{d}\mathbf{l}\times\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|^3},$$
where $O$ is a circle of radius $a$.

Let's parametrise the circle in the usual way: $\mathbf{r}=(a\sin(\theta),a\cos(\theta),b)$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. Then the line element becomes $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{l} = (a\cos(\theta),-a\sin(\theta),0)\mathrm{d}\theta$ and
$$\mathrm{d}\mathbf{l}\times\mathbf{r}= (-ab\sin(\theta),-ab\cos(\theta),a^2)\mathrm{d}\theta,$$ thus

$$\mathbf{B} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{I}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}^3}(-ab\sin(\theta),-ab\cos(\theta),a^2)\mathrm{d}\theta.$$
We may evaluate this componentwise to get
$$\frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi\sqrt{a^2+b^2}^3}(ab\cos(\theta),-ab\sin(\theta),a^2\theta)|_0^{2\pi} = \frac{a^2\mu_0 I}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}^3}(0,0,1).$$